# How to exclude just one folder from ReWriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my current RewriteRule: RewriteRule ^products(/.*)*$ products.php
I would like it to rewrite for products/anything but not for products/shopping-cart I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
RewriteRule: RewriteRule ^products(?!/shopping-cart)(/.)$ products.php
```

`(?!/shopping-cart)` is a negative lookahead that ensures that what follows is not `/shopping-cart`

As @anubhava points out, `(/.)` looks suspicious. What you want is probably either `(/?)` (to match an optional `/`) or `(/.*)` to match the tail end.

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: +1 this should work but `(/.)$` looks suspicious as it will match only slash and one character after `products`